# .bashrc: syntax error near unexpected token '('

Tags: bash, path

I use the Windows Subsystem For Linux. On launching Ubuntu, I get this errors:

```
-bash: /home/divyansh/.bashrc: line 119: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/divyansh/.bashrc: line 119: `export PATH=/mnt/z/usr/local/bin:/mnt/z/usr/local/bin:/home/divyansh/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Python38/Scripts:/mnt/c/Python38:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/MinGW/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/pbox:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/tools:/mnt/c/Users/asus/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Users/asus/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/snap/bin'
```

The '(' token appears only once in the line

> :/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:

. I do not understand why this error is caused. What can I do to clear this? If I leave it as it is, how does it affect the respective path variables?

Comment: What does `echo path` show? Did you add this entry manually or was it installed by Oracle?

Comment: @ajgringo619, `echo path` will output just `path` in almost any shell. `echo $path` would likely output an empty string in Bash, while `echo $PATH`, or preferably `echo "$PATH"` to avoid word-splitting effects, would output the value of the `PATH` variable. Not that it helps here, the value would just be whatever it was before the failed `export` command.

Comment: Doh! How did I miss that!

Comment: Quoting the whole string as PATH='/mnt/......' has removed the error on startup. @ajgringo619 No, I don't remember adding this entry manually. I do not know if it was Oracle or Windows that added it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With regard to the shell syntax, `(` is a special character (like `;`, `>`, `&` etc.), it can't appear as part of an assigned value without being escaped or quoted. It's used e.g. to start subshells, but as you noticed, in most cases it just causes a syntax error. (Unlike, say `&`, which would just silently end the command.)

However, the parenthesis aren't your only problem, you also have whitespace in the path. That's not a syntax error, but changes the meaning of the command. `export PATH=/mnt/c/Program Files/Somepath` means to assign `/mnt/c/Program` to `PATH`, and to export a variable called `Files/Somepath`, which also causes an error because the slash is not valid in a variable name.

You'll need to either escape all the parenthesis and spaces, as in `Program\ Files\ \(x86\)`, or simply quote the whole string:

```
PATH='/mnt/z/usr/local/bin:...:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:...'
```

or just parts of it, though that may be harder to read:

```
PATH=/mnt/z/usr/local/bin:...:'/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath':...
```

(Note that you can't do both inside each other, `PATH='/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/...'` would assign a string containing literal backslashes.)

Answer (score 3):

Add an escape character `\` before each parenthesis:

`Program Files \(x86\)/`

Comment: Escaping the parentheses is a good solution. Another option is to quote the quote the string.

Comment: The string also contains a number of spaces, which will also cause trouble. It's be better to quote the whole thing.